# postfixadmin error Table 'postfixadmin.config' doesn't exist

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, postfix

I am trying to get postfixadmin to work on my Ubuntu 17.10 system. This is the error I am getting:

```
DEBUG INFORMATION:
Invalid query: Table 'postfixadmin.config' doesn't exist

Check your error_log for the failed query.

Please check the documentation and website for more information.
```

the `/var/log/apache2/error_log` shows some permission denied error:

```
[Sun Apr 15 01:11:16.468872 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 3513] [client 76.80.54.221:55168] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_otkuleekb07jjoab4q7utomggc, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /usr/share/postfixadmin/common.php on line 26
[Sun Apr 15 01:11:16.468894 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 3513] [client 76.80.54.221:55168] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in /usr/share/postfixadmin/common.php on line 26
[Sun Apr 15 01:11:16.468922 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 3513] [client 76.80.54.221:55168] PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /usr/share/postfixadmin/common.php on line 30
[Sun Apr 15 01:11:16.468945 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 3513] [client 76.80.54.221:55168] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_otkuleekb07jjoab4q7utomggc, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in
```

A MySQL database for postfixadmin has been started, but the script did not add any tables.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that running `https://yourdomainname/postfixadmin/setup.php` helped me find the problem. And that in fact the table `config` was missing, because the install process never got triggered. It was using `setup.php` that made things start to fall in place.

Comment: Good point. I added more text.